# Makefile link step doesn't properly link obj files

Tags: makefile, linker

I have a problem with linking all the generated obj files into an executable with my current make setup. My directory structure is as follows (provided for reference):

- root

  - bin
  - include
  - project1 ... projectN
  - Makefile
- root/bin

  - project1 ... projectN

    - bin
    - obj
- Project1 (for example)

  - include
  - src
  - Makefile

As you can see, I store multiple subprojects under the same directory and use recursive calls to `make` to build each project. First it gathers all the source and header files from a specific project and it compiles them storing the resulting obj files in `root/bin/project/obj`. From here, I want to link all the obj files and generate an executable file that will be stored under the `root/bin/project/bin` directory.

The problem is that, by using the current Makefile configuration, my linker (MSVC link.exe) can only see the first obj file in the obj dir. Makefile provided below to see the compile and link commands:

```
# expands to root/bin/projname/bin
TARGET_DIR := $(BINARY_DIR)/$(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(CURDIR)))/bin
#expands to root/bin/projname/obj
OBJ_DIR := $(BINARY_DIR)/$(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(CURDIR)))/obj
# expands to a list of all the obj files created from the source files (a.obj, b.obj..)
OBJECTS := \
    $(notdir $(patsubst %.cpp,%.obj,$(patsubst %.c,%.obj,$(SOURCES))))
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/*.cpp)

# default target
all: dirs $(TARGET).exe

# Link
$(TARGET).exe: $(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJECTS)
    $(LNK) $(LIB_PATH) $(LIBS) /OUT:$(TARGET_DIR)/$@ $(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJECTS)

# Compile
$(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) /c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) /Fo$(OBJ_DIR)/ /EHsc $(SOURCES)

.PHONY: build
dirs:
    $(MKDIR) $(TARGET_DIR)
    $(MKDIR) $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(MKDIR) $(TEST_DIR)
```

The error I am encountering is as follows, during the linking process:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64 > NUL && link /NOLOGO /MACHINE:X64  /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64"  /DEFAULTLIB:shell32.lib /OUT:../bin/project1/bin/project1.exe ../bin/project1/obj/main.obj sort.obj
```

As you can see, it only links against the first obj file inside the objdir, while trying to link against a second obj file in the Makefile dir, this of course causes an error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'sort.obj'

Update: Solution proposed in the accepted answer works. Will leave the final version below.

```
# expands to root/bin/projname/bin
TARGET_DIR := $(BINARY_DIR)/$(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(CURDIR)))/bin
#expands to root/bin/projname/obj
OBJ_DIR := $(BINARY_DIR)/$(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(CURDIR)))/obj
# expands to a list of all the obj files created from the source files (a.obj, b.obj..)
OBJECTS := \
    $(notdir $(patsubst %.cpp,%.obj,$(patsubst %.c,%.obj,$(SOURCES))))
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/*.cpp)

# default target
all: dirs $(TARGET).exe

# Link
$(TARGET).exe: $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(OBJECTS)))
    $(LNK) $(LIB_PATH) $(LIBS) /OUT:$(TARGET_DIR)/$@ $^

# Compile
$(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) /c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) /Fo$(OBJ_DIR)/ /EHscT $(SOURCES)

.PHONY: build
dirs:
    $(MKDIR) $(TARGET_DIR)
    $(MKDIR) $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(MKDIR) $(TEST_DIR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not right:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/$(OBJECTS)
```

What does this expand to?  Let's say `OBJECTS` is `foo.o bar.o baz.o` and `OBJDIR` is `obj`.  Then the above expands to:

```
obj/foo.o bar.o baz.o
```

which is clearly not what you want.  If you want to prefix every word in a list with a value you can't just put the value before the entire list.  You need to use something like:

```
$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(OBJECTS))
```

Comment: thank you, i will try it when i get home :)